# How to inline HTML elements that are normally block, specifically headings, labels, input and buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, input, google-chrome-extension

Title. I specifically want to inline a label, input, and button for my dictionary chrome extension. So I want to display

```
Define:[           INPUT               ] DEFINE
```

Where the [] is the input and DEFINE is the button. I can't figure out how to align these at all...

This is MY HTML:

```html
    <label>Define: </label>
    <input id="term" type="text">
    <button id="button">Define</button>
```

It just comes out as

```
Define:
[         ]
DEFINE
```

Thanks for the CSS help!

Comment: if width is large enough for them, they will stand on one line. what CSS are you using aside ?

Comment: hmm. it would appear it does. My chrome extension has a small popup and so the width is pretty small so none of it is on the same line :\. I am not using any CSS, but i was fiddling around with float and display to no avail.

Comment: try resize the popup or add to it : white-space:nowrap;  difficult to say since i do not know how you are coding this popup :) i updated your tag question

Comment: perfect. i didn't think to resize the popup for some reason. Thanks a lot! First time using stackoverflow was helpful.

Comment: The code you have in the question does not reproduce what you state it does. Just running the snippet in the question shows `Define:[           INPUT               ] DEFINE`, which is what you state you want. Please provide a [MCVE] which actually duplicates the problem. This may require you to provide sufficient code to duplicate this as a Chrome extension (i.e. including your *manifest.json* and enough of your popup HTML/JavaScript as is needed to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the `display: inline-block` property. it would like something like this in your css.

input,label,button { display: inline-block; }

Hope I helped.

Comment: as commented on other answer, the popup where stands those elements **is not wide enough**, so they wrap down . Did you run the snippet in the question and read comments below  ?

Comment: Sorry. I did not. Have you tried reducing the width of the text field with <input type='text' size='x'>? That's the only thing I can advise.